# A strange issue when using Java's Future/Callable

Tags: java, concurrency, future, callable

I believe I understand how Future/Callable works pretty well. Like code below (2nd section), cacheLoader1 and cacheLoader2 are two instances of a Callable implementation, and its call() method is to load a cache

```
@Override
public Cache call() throws Exception {
  cache.loadCache();
  return cache;
}
```

and I intend to use two threads to run the tasks and merge the returned caches. I understand future#get() will block till the respective thread is completed. The problem I encounter is, however, it never returns. I commented out the single line of Future#get() and it proceeded.

I looked into the code in cache#loadCache() and find it tries to retrieve data from a DB table, like service.getData(), underneath it call DAO which in turn use Spring's getSqlMapClientTemplate and iBatis SQL. If I reinstate the commented Future#get, the DAO never returns.

```
List<Future<Cache>> list = new ArrayList<Future<Cache>>();
Future<Cache> f = es.submit(cacheLoader1);
list.add(f);
f = es.submit(cacheLoader2);
list.add(f);

for(Future<Cache> future: list){
  logger.debug("done with {}",future.get());
}
```

I have a hard time understanding what might be wrong. Any help? Is that because the throws Exception clause in the call method?

p.s. To clarify further:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
class CacheLoader implements Callable<Cache>{
  ....
  @Override
  public Cache call() throws Exception {
    cache.loadCache();
    return cache;
  }
}
CacheLoader cacheLoader1, cacheLoader2;
```

**UPDATE**:

I seemed to find out the root cause, yet need advice what the best solution might be. First my apology that the earlier info is not sufficient for people to pinpoint the issue.

This is a Spring project and the code in the 2nd section is inside a **init-method** called "*init*" of a bean. The aforementioned DAO is also registered in Spring. So the problem seems to be that the method "init" is hanging up bcoz of the block f.get() and Spring config can't be completed; is it kind of circular dependencies? I still haven't figured out the best approach to it...

Thanks,

Jon

Comment: What is `es`?  What is `cacheLoader1`?

Comment: It must be something in the call to `cache.loadCache();` - try replacing that call with a dummy print statement to see if it finishes. If your print statement works, then something in `loadCache()` is hanging.

Comment: This seems like it should work.  Does it work if you call cacheLoader1.call() in the code instead of submitting it to the Executor?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it's easy.

In the init-method, I created another thread like below

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
es.execute(cacheLoader);
```

and CacheLoader implements Runnable (**es1** is another instance of ExecuteService):

```
public class CacheLoader implements Runnable{
  public void run() {
    Future<Cache> f1 = es1.submit(new Callable<Cache>(){
        @Override
        public Cache call(){
            cache1.loadCache();
            return cache1;
        }
    });

    Future<Cache> f2 = es1.submit(new Callable<Cache>(){
        @Override
        public Cache call(){
            cache2.loadCache();
            return cache2;
        }
    });
    Cache c1 = f1.get();
    Cache c2 = f2.get();
  } //~end of run() ~
}
```